# Destroy [reveal]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[reveal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reveal) is completely worthless. There are 27 questions with nothing in common, except a couple that are for something called Foundation Reveal which seems to have a tag at [zurb-reveal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-reveal). But most are just about the asker wanting something to appear.

Comment: There seems to be 3 reasons from that list of questions. 1) I want to reveal an element, 2) I meant to use [reveal.js], 3) using a component in [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html) (which I haven't figured out yet). I'm in the process of cutting down everything in item 1.

Comment: Seems to me that this is a case of manual disambiguation + burnination

Comment: I killed a few that should have been `zurb-reveal`. We're down to one question that should be deleted entirely.

Comment: This should really be tagged as Status-completed as a user has purged the tag.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After a good 45 minutes of combined work, the tag has been emptied.

Now we wait for the auto-job to delete the tag.